# Angular 8 return observable after chain of async calls

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a simple function that calls 3 async functions one after another like this:

```js
getData() {
    this.getUsers('2')
        .pipe(
        flatMap((data: any) => {  
            return this.getPosts(data.id);
        }),
        flatMap((data: any) => {            
            return this.getPosts(data[0].userId);
        })
        ).subscribe(results => {    
        return new Observable((observer) => {
        observer.next(results);
        observer.complete();
        });
    });
}
```

I would like someway to be able to call something like:
`this.getdata.subscribe()` and that be called when all 3 flatMaps are completed. I assume I would have to have the getData() function return an observable which I tried to do at the bottom but it does not work and I am not able to call .subscribe on the getData() function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t4qgjo?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

```
getData() {
    return this.getUsers('2')
      .pipe(
        flatMap((data: any) => {  
          return this.getPosts(data.id);
        }),
        flatMap((data: any) => {            
          return this.getPosts(data[0].userId);
        })
      )
  }
```

Comment: Does not work, I get `Cannot read property subscribe of undefined`

Comment: Can you check the demo? Its with dummy APIs